# INT stays the same outside FOR loop

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

Function "f_vowels" works; it prints the number of common vowels the two strings have. The other one, "two_c", should work as well; it gives true if the two strings share at least two common letters in the same position. My problem is the third one, cause it should print those letters but always prints the message "Strings don't have 2 common letters". I think I know why: I'm increasing "dim" with a FOR loop, but the boolean function's still working with the original "dim". How do I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

// functions' calls

void f_vowels(string, string);
bool two_c(int);
void print_2c(string, string, int, int);

// main
int main(){
string s1, s2;
int i, j, vowels;
int l1, l2;
char vow, c1, c2;

cout << "Enter your string: ";
getline(cin, s1);
cout << "\n";

cout << "Enter your string: ";
getline(cin, s2);
cout << "\n";

f_vowels(s1, s2);

int dim=0;
char common[dim];

for (int i=0; i<l1 && i<l2; i++){
    if (s1[i]==s2[i])
    {
    common[dim++];
    }
}

two_c(dim);

if (two_c(dim)==true){
print_2c(s1, s2, l1, l2);
} 

else cout << "Strings don't have 2 common letters.";

}

//functions

//common vowels

void f_vowels(string s1, string s2){

int l1=s1.length();
char c1[l1];
s1.copy(c1, l1);

int l2=s2.length();
char c2[l2];
s2.copy(c2, l2);

int vowels=0;
char vow[]={'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};

for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<l1 && j<l2; j++){
    if (c1[j]=vow[i] && c2[j]==vow[i]){
        vowels++;
        }
      }
    }
    cout << vowels << "\n\n";    
    }

 // true if strings have at least 2 common letters in the same position

bool two_c(int dim){

if (dim<2){
return false;
}
else return true;

}

// print boolean function

void print_2c(string s1, string s2, int l1, int l2){

int dim=0;
char common[dim];

    for (int i=0; i<l1 && i<l2; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<l1 && j<l2; j++){
            if (s1[i]==s2[i])
            common[j]=s1[i];
            cout << common[j] << "is a common letter. \n";      
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: `int dim=0; char common[dim];` doesn't look right

Comment: `dim` and `common` in `print_2c()` are not the same as `dim` and `common` in `main()`, that could be the source of your confusion

Comment: Yes! Exactly. How do I make them the same?

Comment: either make them global, or pass references to the function as parameters

Comment: Hi @Progrm, I show you how to pass in common array as a parameter in my answer below

Comment: Just noticed, thank you so much!!

Comment: @Progrm Great! Be sure to mark it as the selected answer!

Answer (score 1):

Couple issues here.

This logic:

```
int dim=0;
char common[dim];

for (int i=0; i<l1 && i<l2; i++){
    if (s1[i]==s2[i])
    {
    common[dim++];
    }
}
```

...Does nothing. common[dim++] performs a lookup and throws out the value because it’s not getting assigned to anything. What it seems like you’re trying is to determine the the array size dim or at least increment it’s size based on the number of expected matches. To do that, you must first calculate dim before you declare you’re array. So:

```
int dim=0;

for (int i=0; i<l1 && i<l2; i++){
    if (s1[i]==s2[i])
    {
    dim++;
    }
}

char common[dim]; //won’t compile
```

This approach will not compile though because the compiler can’t know the size of dim until the program runs. You’ll need to dynamically allocate the array using ‘new’ you if you still think an array is the way to do this (consider std::vector).

```
int dim=0;

for (int i=0; i<l1 && i<l2; i++){
    if (s1[i]==s2[i])
    {
    dim++;
    }
}

char* common = new char[dim];
```

ALSO:

Regarding

```
void print_2c(string s1, string s2, int l1, int l2){

 int dim=0;
char common[dim]; //a local array, not what you e setup

for (int i=0; i<l1 && i<l2; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<l1 && j<l2; j++){
        if (s1[i]==s2[i])
        common[j]=s1[i];
        cout << common[j] << "is a common letter. \n";      
        }
  }
}
```

Whatever logic is running here is being performed on a local and empty array called common, different from the common you’ve created prior to this call. It seems you want access to you array. You’ll need to pass in common in some form (probably as an argument) and then you’ll be able to use what you’ve setup. So:

```
void print_2c(string s1, string s2, int l1, int l2, char* common, const int dim){


for (int i=0; i<l1 && i<l2; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<l1 && j<l2; j++){
        if (s1[i]==s2[i])
        common[j]=s1[i];
        cout << common[j] << "is a common letter. \n";      
        }
  }
}
```

And called as:

```
print_2c(s1,s2,l1,l2,common,dim);
```

LASTLY:
this logic:

```
for (int i=0; i<l1 && i<l2; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<l1 && j<l2; j++){
        if (s1[i]==s2[i])
        common[j]=s1[i];
        cout << common[j] << "is a common letter. \n";      
        }
  }
```

Probably isn’t doing what you want.  In the inner loop, when the char in s1 matches s2, all values in common up to min(l1,l2) are set to that char, and it’ll just print out “is a common letter” for that char repeatedly. Common will stay filled with all entries being the same char until the next match when all values get overwritten and set to the new char value. Not what you want.

If common instead was an array of bools and each index represented an eligible matching character (ie vowel), you could do something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<l1 && i<l2; i++){
    //no inner loop needed
        if (s1[i]==s2[i])
        common[s1[i]]=true;
        cout << s1[i] << "is a common letter. \n";      
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a char array with size 0.

```
int dim=0;//<-- Here!!
char common[dim];
```

Change dim for the proper length (s1 or s2 length) and I think you would solve your problem